# svg: one svg gradiant overlaps another svg on a page

Tags: html, css, svg

I have two SVG in a HTML file. but the problem is I can't give a different gradient to them. the second SVG is filled with the first svg's gradient color.

First `svg`:

```
<div class="wave">
    <svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="transition duration-300 ease-in-out delay-150">
        <defs>
            <linearGradient id="gradient">
                <stop offset="5%" stop-color="#7f00ffff"></stop>
                <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#e100ffff"></stop>
            </linearGradient>
        </defs>
        <path
            d="M 0,400 C 0,400 0,200 0,200 C 199.86666666666667,226.8 399.73333333333335,253.6 559,240 C 718.2666666666667,226.4 836.9333333333334,172.4 977,159 C 1117.0666666666666,145.6 1278.5333333333333,172.8 1440,200 C 1440,200 1440,400 1440,400 Z"
            stroke="none"
            stroke-width="0"
            fill="url(#gradient)"
            class="transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out delay-150"
            transform="rotate(-180 720 200)"
        ></path>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Second `svg`:

```
<div class="wave">
    <svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="transition duration-300 ease-in-out delay-150">
        <defs>
            <linearGradient id="gradient">
                <stop offset="5%" stop-color="red"></stop>
                <stop offset="95%" stop-color="green"></stop>
            </linearGradient>
        </defs>
        <path
            d="M 0,400 C 0,400 0,200 0,200 C 199.86666666666667,226.8 399.73333333333335,253.6 559,240 C 718.2666666666667,226.4 836.9333333333334,172.4 977,159 C 1117.0666666666666,145.6 1278.5333333333333,172.8 1440,200 C 1440,200 1440,400 1440,400 Z"
            stroke="none"
            stroke-width="0"
            fill="url(#gradient)"
            class="transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out delay-150"
            transform="rotate(-180 720 200)"
        ></path>
    </svg>
</div>
```

in the second svg I give red and green gradiant. but it is not applied.
why It is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the same `id` for different `svg`. This is `#svg` and `#gradient`. Technically, the second `svg` receives the parameters of the first `svg` according to `id`. For this reason, both your `svg` have the **same** gradient. The value of this attribute must be unique for each page:

> The HTML `id` attribute is used to specify a **unique** id for an HTML element. You cannot have more than one element with the same id in an HTML document.

For the second `svg`, use a different id value for `<svg id="" viewBox="0 0 1440 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="transition duration-300 ease-in-out delay-150">`, `<linearGradient id="">` and `fill="url()"`.

For the value of the `id` of the second `svg`, I indicated `#svg2` and `#gradient2` (for example).

```html
<div class="wave">
    <svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="transition duration-300 ease-in-out delay-150">
        <defs>
            <linearGradient id="gradient">
                <stop offset="5%" stop-color="#7f00ffff"></stop>
                <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#e100ffff"></stop>
            </linearGradient>
        </defs>
        <path
            d="M 0,400 C 0,400 0,200 0,200 C 199.86666666666667,226.8 399.73333333333335,253.6 559,240 C 718.2666666666667,226.4 836.9333333333334,172.4 977,159 C 1117.0666666666666,145.6 1278.5333333333333,172.8 1440,200 C 1440,200 1440,400 1440,400 Z"
            stroke="none"
            stroke-width="0"
            fill="url(#gradient)"
            class="transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out delay-150"
            transform="rotate(-180 720 200)"
        ></path>
    </svg>
</div>

<div class="wave">
    <svg id="svg2" viewBox="0 0 1440 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="transition duration-300 ease-in-out delay-150">
        <defs>
            <linearGradient id="gradient2">
                <stop offset="5%" stop-color="red"></stop>
                <stop offset="95%" stop-color="green"></stop>
            </linearGradient>
        </defs>
        <path
            d="M 0,400 C 0,400 0,200 0,200 C 199.86666666666667,226.8 399.73333333333335,253.6 559,240 C 718.2666666666667,226.4 836.9333333333334,172.4 977,159 C 1117.0666666666666,145.6 1278.5333333333333,172.8 1440,200 C 1440,200 1440,400 1440,400 Z"
            stroke="none"
            stroke-width="0"
            fill="url(#gradient2)"
            class="transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out delay-150"
            transform="rotate(-180 720 200)"
        ></path>
    </svg>
</div>
```